# Matlab Calling Functions

Tags: matlab

So here is the question I am trying to solve in matlab,

Determine the effect of varying Δx on the computed result for the second derivative, for the function f(x) = 5 + 10x – 4x^2 + 6x^3. The second derivative is to be determined at x = 1. Using matlab, calculate the second derivative at x = 1 with Δx = 0.5, 0.1, 0.05, and 0.01. Compare the results obtained with the exact value of 28

Since I am a novice with Matlab here are the steps I wanted to do,

1) ask the user for an input of del x

2) the second derivative equation is [f(x+del x)-2f(x)+f(x-del x)] / (del x)^2

3) since x=1, i essentially want to call the f(x) eqn (given above in statement) within the second derivative equation and solve based on the input of del x

I also want to keep all sig figs as we are comparing the 28 to the computed value which is expected to be ~28.0000001

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far? Please refer to [ask]

Comment: Your three steps sound reasonable enough. Which of the three steps are you having problems with, particularly?

Answer (score 2):

Your function:

```
f = @(x) 5 + 10*x - 4*x.^2 + 6*x.^3;
```

1) Ask the user for an input of `del x`

```
dx = input('Enter Value for del x: ')
```

2) The second derivative equation is `[f(x+del x)-2f(x)+f(x-del x)] / (del x)^2`

```
d2fdx2 = @(x) ( f(x + dx) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - dx) ) ./ (dx^2);
```

I've included element-wise operators (`./`) so you can input vectors.

3) Since `x=1`, I essentially want to call the `f(x)` equation within the second derivative equation and solve based on the input of `del x`.

You can evaluate these functions at any point you wish:

```
f(1)
% ans = 17

% When dx = 0.5,
d2fdx2(1)
% ans = 28
```

Putting this all together:

```
dx = input('Enter Value for del x: ')
f = @(x) 5 + 10*x - 4*x.^2 + 6*x.^3;
d2fdx2 = @(x) ( f(x + dx) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - dx) ) ./ (dx.^2);

% Long decimal expansion
format long

% Evaluate result
d2fdx2(1)
```

Although given your question, I'm not sure you actually need user input? If it's just for your specified values, you could do this:

```
clear;clc;

k = 1;
derivatives = zeros(4,1);

f = @(x) 5 + 10*x - 4*x.^2 + 6*x.^3;

for dx = [0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01]

    d2fdx2 = @(x) ( f(x + dx) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - dx) ) ./ (dx^2);
    derivatives(k) = d2fdx2(1);
    k = k + 1;

end

% derivatives = [28.000000000000000
%                28.000000000000107
%                28.000000000000107
%                28.000000000041325]
```

Note that the method/implementation seems to have some interesting instabilities at these values, since you would expect it to be more accurate with smaller `dx`. For instance if you start with `dx=0.5` and repeatedly half it, the answer remains at `28.000...`.